Discord modal error on submission. The modal window gives a "Something went wrong" error, but no errors in console
When I submit the modal just gives a Something went wrong error.
Here is the section of my code:
// Handle Submit Score Button
if (customId.startsWith('submit-score')) {
  console.log(`Received customId: ${customId}`);

  const matchId = customId.split('-')[2]; // Extract matchId from customId
  console.log(`Extracted matchId: ${matchId}, Type: ${typeof matchId}`);

  if (!matchId) {
    return interaction.reply({ content: 'Invalid match ID.', ephemeral: true });
  }

  const guildId = interaction.guild.id;

  try {
    const matches = await getMatchesFromMongo(guildId);

    if (!matches || matches.length === 0) {
      return interaction.reply({ content: 'No matches found for this guild.', ephemeral: true });
    }

    const match = matches.find(m => m.match.id === parseInt(matchId));

    if (!match) {
      return interaction.reply({ content: 'Match not found.', ephemeral: true });
    }

    const participants = await fetchParticipants(guildId);
    const participantsList = participants.map(p => p.participant);

    const teamAName = getParticipantName(match.match.player1_id, participantsList);
    const teamBName = getParticipantName(match.match.player2_id, participantsList);

    const modal = new ModalBuilder()
      .setCustomId(`submitScoreModal-${matchId}`)
      .setTitle('Submit Score');

    const teamAScoreInput = new TextInputBuilder()
      .setCustomId('teamAScore')
      .setLabel(`Enter score for ${teamAName}`)
      .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
      .setPlaceholder(`${teamAName} Score`)
      .setRequired(true);

    const teamBScoreInput = new TextInputBuilder()
      .setCustomId('teamBScore')
      .setLabel(`Enter score for ${teamBName}`)
      .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
      .setPlaceholder(`${teamBName} Score`)
      .setRequired(true);

    const teamARow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(teamAScoreInput);
    const teamBRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(teamBScoreInput);

    modal.addComponents(teamARow, teamBRow);

    await interaction.showModal(modal);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching matches or participants from MongoDB:', error);
    return interaction.reply({ content: 'Error fetching match data.', ephemeral: true });
  }
  return;
}

// Handle Modal Submission
else if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
  console.log('Modal submitted with customId:', interaction.customId);

  if (interaction.customId.startsWith('submitScoreModal')) {
    try {
      // Step 1: Extract the match ID
      const matchId = interaction.customId.split('-')[1];
      console.log(`Extracted matchId: ${matchId}, Type: ${typeof matchId}`);

      // Step 2: Safely extract the scores from the modal
      let scoreTeamA, scoreTeamB;
      try {
        scoreTeamA = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('teamAScore');
        scoreTeamB = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('teamBScore');
        console.log(`Extracted scores -> Team A: ${scoreTeamA}, Team B: ${scoreTeamB}`);
      } catch (fieldError) {
        console.error('Error extracting scores from modal fields:', fieldError);
        return interaction.reply({ content: 'Failed to extract scores. Please try again.', ephemeral: true });
      }

      // Step 3: Check if matchId or scores are missing
      if (!matchId || !scoreTeamA || !scoreTeamB) {
        console.error('Missing matchId or scores');
        return interaction.reply({ content: 'Invalid match details or missing scores.', ephemeral: true });
      }

      // Ensure the scores are numeric
      if (isNaN(scoreTeamA) || isNaN(scoreTeamB)) {
        console.error('Invalid score values. Scores must be numbers.');
        return interaction.reply({ content: 'Please enter valid numeric scores.', ephemeral: true });
      }

      // Step 4: Log the guild ID
      const guildId = interaction.guild.id;
      console.log(`Guild ID: ${guildId}`);

      // Step 5: Acknowledge the interaction
      try {
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
        console.log('Reply successfully deferred');
      } catch (deferError) {
        console.error('Error deferring reply:', deferError);
        return;
      }

      // Step 6: Fetch matches from MongoDB
      console.log(`Fetching matches from MongoDB for guildId: ${guildId}`);
      let matches;
      try {
        matches = await getMatchesFromMongo(guildId);
      } catch (fetchError) {
        console.error('Error fetching matches from MongoDB:', fetchError);
        return interaction.followUp({ content: 'Error fetching match data.', ephemeral: true });
      }

      // Step 7: Check if matches were fetched
      if (!matches || matches.length === 0) {
        console.error('No matches found in MongoDB');
        return interaction.followUp({ content: 'No matches found for this guild.', ephemeral: true });
      }

      // Step 8: Search for the match with the extracted matchId
      console.log(`Looking for match with matchId: ${matchId}`);
      const match = matches.find(m => m.match.id === parseInt(matchId));

      if (!match) {
        console.error('Match not found in MongoDB');
        return interaction.followUp({ content: 'Match data not found.', ephemeral: true });
      }

      // Step 9: Log the match details for verification
      console.log(`Match found: ${JSON.stringify(match)}`);

      // Step 10: Determine the winner and loser based on the scores
      let winnerId, loserId;
      if (parseInt(scoreTeamA) > parseInt(scoreTeamB)) {
        winnerId = match.match.player1_id;
        loserId = match.match.player2_id;
      } else {
        winnerId = match.match.player2_id;
        loserId = match.match.player1_id;
      }

      console.log(`Winner ID: ${winnerId}, Loser ID: ${loserId}`);

      // Step 11: Submit the match score
      console.log(`Submitting score for match ${matchId}`);
      try {
        await submitMatchScore(
          interaction.guild,
          matchId,
          scoreTeamA,
          scoreTeamB,
          match.match.player1_id,
          match.match.player2_id,
          match.match.round,
          null,
          match.proofrequired,
          interaction.user.id
        );
      } catch (submitError) {
        console.error('Error submitting match score:', submitError);
        return interaction.followUp({ content: 'Error submitting match score.', ephemeral: true });
      }

      // Step 12: Update the match result in MongoDB
      const scoresCsv = `${scoreTeamA}-${scoreTeamB}`;
      try {
        await updateMatchResult(guildId, matchId, winnerId, loserId, scoresCsv);
      } catch (updateError) {
        console.error('Error updating match result in MongoDB:', updateError);
        return interaction.followUp({ content: 'Error updating match data.', ephemeral: true });
      }

      // Step 13: Confirm successful score submission
      console.log(`Score submitted and match updated successfully for match ${matchId}`);
      await interaction.followUp({ content: `Score submitted successfully for match ${matchId}.`, ephemeral: true });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error handling modal submission:', error);
      await interaction.followUp({ content: 'An error occurred while submitting scores. Please try again later.', ephemeral: true });
    }
  }
  return;
}

I have tried adding in console logs but I do not get anything in the debug console after the modal is shown and I try to submit. So I am at a stand still as I have no other ideas on why this is not working. I am relatively new to discord.js and coding so maybe I have something wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

The most likely reason is that you're missing the interactionCreate event listener for handling the modal submission. If that listener isn’t set up, the bot won’t know how to handle the modal data when it’s submitted, and that’s why you’re seeing nothing in the console after submission.
Make sure you’ve got something like this:
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
    // Handle your modal submission logic here
  }
});

Without this, your modal submission just won’t trigger.
